# Sharepoint list with multiple attachment

Tags: 2013

I have a requirement , based on different drop down selection , display attachment fields . 
Eg : 
Dropdown selected as A -> attach a file , 
if selected B attach file etc .

Similarly I have 3 drop downs . How can i achieve this ? because list have a single "Attachment" column . (I dont want info paths)

Thanks

Comment: Whatever dropdown option you selects it has to show at least one file control. And any attachment, it uploads as a list attachment. If I am analysis is right, why do you need three controls and upload from one and do the same function. Instead of show/hide file control you can apply business case to one file control.

Comment: How to distinguish between 3 different file loaded ? i want all 2 columns with respective attachments . (Dont want 1 column with 3 attachments)

Comment: Do you mean file extension?

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly what I have been looking for.

Best I can find is that you need to use **Document Sets**.

Check below link for more information: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint/comments/1ujpvd/multiple_named_attachment_fields_on_a_list_in/